# incorrect syntax near ')'... I do not get it

Tags: sql, syntax

My code

```
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
with Documents as
(
select TOP 100 PERCENT d.LeEn, d.Wacode, d.Waname, d.Arcode, d.Arname, sum(d.Quantity) as Quantity from Documents as d
where (select max(DocumentDate) from Documents as d where d.DocumentCode = 'INW') <= d.DocumentDate
group by d.LeEn, d.WarehouseCode, d.Waname, d.Arcode, d.Arname
order by d.LeEn, d.WarehouseCode, d.Arcode
)
)
```

and I am getting this

Incorrect syntax near ')'.

any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WITH` should be before a `SELECT`.  In this case, the CTE seems unnecessary, so just do:

```
RETURN (
 select TOP 100 PERCENT d.LeEn, d.Wacode, d.Waname, d.Arcode, d.Arname, sum(d.Quantity) as Quantity
 from Documents as d
 where (select max(DocumentDate)
        from Documents d
        where d.DocumentCode = 'INW'
       ) <= d.DocumentDate
 group by d.LeEn, d.WarehouseCode, d.Waname, d.Arcode, d.Arname
 order by d.LeEn, d.WarehouseCode, d.Arcode
)
```

The `ORDER BY` and `TOP 100` are utterly superfluous.  SQL Server does not guarantee that the results are ordered.

Comment: Am I missing a subtlety that explains the presence of `TOP 100 PERCENT` in that? Isn't it pointless?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder . . . I left it in.  The OP probably thinks the results will be ordered by using the `TOP`.  That is not guaranteed, but it does no harm other than doing an unnecessary sort (which is after a `GROUP BY` so isn't that bad).

Comment: @JenisWunder: I wasn't suggesting it was a fix (Gordon's already suggested a fix). It just seems pointless to say `TOP 100 PERCENT` when by definition, 100% is "all".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks. As there's *already* an `ORDER BY`... :-) (Not giving you a hard time for leaving it in, was just curious if there was something I was missing; I'm only mid-level at T-SQL.)